# Continuation abstraction

Tags: haskell, monads, abstraction

In a general exercise about concurrency based on this [article](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/jespera/downloads/jfp99-monad.ps).

We have:

```
-- a is the result type on which after we continue
type Continuation a = a-> Action

type ContinuationPseudoMonad a = Continuation a -> Action
-- pseudoMonad because it will need Concurrent wrapper Monad:
-- so as to define bind operation and return operation on it

data Concurrent a = Concurrent (ContinuationPseudoMonad a)
```

so `Concurrent a` is a monad we have to implement with its two mandatory laws, return and bind.

Unfortunatly, I find no adequate words for defining more precisely the ContinuationPseudoMonad thing... and if I lack words, I lack abstraction in my mind.

How would you call it ?

Is there a word meaning `Continuation a -> Action` instead of my awkward meaningless `ContinuationPseudoMonad` ?

Action being:

```
data Action = Atom (IO Action)
            | Fork Action Action
            | Stop
```

Comment: Is your question how to define `return` and `>>=` for `Concurrent` as you've defined it above?

Comment: Also, slight typo - I think you mean, `data Concurrent a = Concurrent (ContinuationPseudoMonad a)`, as `data Concurrent a = Concurrent ContinuationPseudoMonad a` is an error.

Comment: I corrected accordingly to your statement. The thing is I don't succeed to grasp what a `Continuation a -> Action' is. A name for this abstraction would be great.

Comment: I think the only word is 'monad without its `newtype` wrapper' (incidentally, `newtype` is better than `data` for `Concurrent` since it doesn't add an extra layer at runtime to represent the `Concurrent` constructor) or 'continuation-passing-style function'.

Comment: I do admire your desire for descriptive names at every level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evident `Concurrent a` is the same as `Cont Action a` where [`Cont`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html#t:Cont) is the continuation monad. Here's a simple explanation for continuations:

1. Consider the function `f :: a -> b` for some arbitrary types `a` and `b`. We want to convert this function into continuation passing style. How do we do so?
2. Let's say we have a continuation `k :: b -> r` which takes the return value of `f` as an input and itself returns a value of an arbitrary type `r`. Following this, we can convert `f` to CPS.
3. Let `g :: a -> (b -> r) -> r` be the CPS version function of `f`. Note that it takes an additional argument (i.e. the continuation `k`) and returns the result of `k` applied to its output `b`.

Let's take a practical example where `f` is the predicate function `odd :: Int -> Bool`:

```hs
odd :: Int -> Bool
odd n = n `mod` 2 == 1
```

Here's the same function written in continuation passing style:

```hs
odd' :: Int -> (Bool -> r) -> r
odd' n k = k (n `mod` 2 == 1)
```

The `(Bool -> r) -> r` part can be abstracted out as the continuation monad:

```hs
data Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }

odd' :: Int -> Cont r Bool
odd' n = return (n `mod` 2 == 1)

instance Monad (Cont r) where
    return a = Cont (\k -> k a)
    m  >>= f = Cont (\k -> runCont m (\a -> runCont (f a) k))
```

Notice that the type of the continuation `k` is `Bool -> r` for some arbitrary type `r`. Hence, the continuation `k` could be any function which takes a `Bool` as an argument. For example:

```hs
cont :: Bool -> IO ()
cont = print

main :: IO ()
main = odd' 21 cont
```

However, in the case of `Concurrent` this `r` is not arbitrary. It has been specialized to `Action`. In fact, we can define `Concurrent` as a type synonym for `Cont Action` as follows:

```hs
type Concurrent = Cont Action
```

Now, we don't need to implement the `Monad` instance for `Concurrent` because it's the same as the `Monad` instance for `Cont r` as defined above.

```hs
runConcurrent :: Concurrent a -> ContinuationPseudoMonad a
runConcurrent (Concurrent g) = g

instance Monad Concurrent where
    return a = Concurrent (\k -> k a)
    m  >>= f = Concurrent (\k -> runConcurrent m (\a -> runConcurrent (f a) k))
```

Note that nowhere in the definition of `instance Monad Concurrent` have we made use of `Action`. That's because `Concurrent = Cont Action` and the monad instance of `Cont r` uses `r` transparently.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reaching for some vocabulary, which is a hard question to phrase. Let's break down what you have into steps, and see if that helps.

```
data Action = Atom (IO Action)
            | Fork Action Action
            | Stop
```

`Action` is an *algebraic data type* with three *constructors*. It is a *corecursive* data type as it is defined in terms of itself.

```
type Continuation a = a -> Action
```

`Continuation a` is a *type alias* for the *function type* `a -> Action`. It is an example of a `contravariant functor`, since we could define a function

```
contramap :: (a -> b) -> Continuation b -> Continuation a
contramap aToB bToAction = aToAction 
  where aToAction = \a -> bToAction (aToB a)
```

Note the reversal - `contramap` takes a function `a -> b` and creates a function `Continuation b -> Continuation a`.

```
type ContinuationPseudoMonad a = Continuation a -> Action
```

`ContinuationPseudoMonad a` is another type alias for a function type, but since `Continuation a` is also a function type, `ContinuationPseudoMonad a` is a type of *higher-order function*, since it takes a function as an argument.

`ContinuationPseudoMonad a` is also a *functor*, but it's a *covariant functor*, as we could define a function

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> ContinuationPseudoMonad a -> ContinuationPseudoMonad b
fmap aToB aToActionToAction = bToActionToAction
  where bToActionToAction = \bToAction -> aToActionToAction (\a -> bToAction (aToB a))
```